# How to make Facebook Login Button segue to alternate View Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, authentication, segue

So I am trying to incorporate a Facebook login screen before a TabBarController. What I have so far is a view controller that first displays a "Login to Facebook" button. Once clicked, it takes you to either the app on the device or to facebook.com. You enter your info, click login, and it takes you back to the same view controller which I now have show the user profile picture, name, email, and a logout button. What I **WANT** to have happen, is once you click login through either the Facebook app or website, it takes you to a another view controller, in my case, a TabBarController. In plain steps:

1. Click the "Login to Facebook" button.
2. Once taken to login screen, enter your information.
3. The app now enters a TabBarController, which is the main home page of the app I am making.

The way the setup is currently, the "button" is a UIView controller with the custom class of the **FBLoginView** drawn from the Facebook SDK. I just need this "button" to segue to my TabBarController once you have entered your login information and clicked login.

*FYI*: The code I am using is the setup that Facebook gives you when using its tutorial for adding a Facebook login to an app. Below is my LoginViewControoler.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];

}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged in.";
    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];

}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}


-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I know of doing this is to put the login button on a modal View Controller that presents itself upon startup (in the initial view controller's viewDidLoad). It then dismisses itself at the end of a successful login attempt, or with dismiss button.